# Derivatives of $\frac{\csc x}{e^{-x}}$ and $\ln\left(\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have tried to mainly ask thoughtful conceptual questions here, but now I am reduced to asking for help on a specific problem that I have been wrestling with for over an hour.

***Disclaimer: I am not a lazy student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus from a textbook.  I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

$$f(x)= \frac{\csc(x)}{e^{-x}}$$
$$f'(x)= ?$$

Answer key says choice (1): $$e^x\csc2x(1-2\cot2x)$$

[image]

2) My answer does not match the answer key.   Is there a typo?
Any guidance is enjoyed...it's driving me nuts!

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}\right)$$

Answer key says choice (2): $$\frac{x^2+6}{x^3+3x}$$

[image]

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. Note that our maths renderer MathJax also works in titles. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Comment: The first is probably a typo, they thought they had $\csc(2x)$ on top. By the way, your work (which is correct for $\frac{\csc x}{e^{-x}}$) would have been somewhat easier if you had made the preliminary simplification to $e^x\csc x$. For the second, I would use "laws of logs" to simplify the expression **before** differentiating. Lots of work saved.

Comment: The textbook answer to the second question is right. You missed a 2 in the first line of your work for the $-u \cdot \frac{dv}{dx} \space $part. It should have been $(-3x^2)\cdot \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{3+x^2}}$

Comment: Andre!  Yes, the first question had a typo.  Good call, it's very obvious now!

Comment: K.Rmth!  Yes, I forgot the chain rule at that step.  Let me add back the (2x) and see if I can finish it the hard way.  (Using Log rules up front sure make it easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, I would recommend re-writing it as:
$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{\sin{x}}$.

Then using the quotient rule with $u=e^x, v=\sin{x},$
we obtain:

$f'(x)=\frac{e^x\sin{x}-e^x\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}}=\frac{e^x(\sin{x}-\cos{x})}{\sin^2{x}}=\frac{e^x}{\sin{x}}\frac{\sin{x}-\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}=e^x\csc{x}(1-\cot{x}).$

I do not think this is equivalent to what was given in the textbook, although Wolfram Alpha agrees with my answer so I am inclined to think it is the correct one.

As for 2, it makes it *considerably* simpler to use log laws first, to show that:
$\ln{\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}}=\ln{3}+2\ln{x}-\frac{1}{2}\ln{(x^2+3)}=g(x)$, say.

Then using the standard derivative rules for logs we get:
$g'(x)=\frac{2}{x}-\frac{x}{x^2+3}=\frac{x^2+6}{x^3+3x}$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the replies.

For #1, it looks like the question meant to say $csc(2x)$
Looks like I solved the original question correctly, 
and I redid the revised problem to match the given solution.  Check!

For #2, yes, the log rules make it a lot easier.  I was able to do it correctly that way.
I also fixed my chain rule error and solved it correctly the "hard way".  Damn, that took me a few tries and quite some time.  But, I am stronger for it.

Thanks!!